# How to update an Azure AD B2C Username sample for sending custom emails with SendGrid?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using [this policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin) for Username-based SUSI extended off of [this starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/LocalAccounts) for local account SUSI. But I had also changed that starter pack for custom verification emails with SendGrid according to the [how-to found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). The requirements for login went from "just use B2C" to "login with a username and any number of users may share a verification email."

I know that TrustFrameworkExtensions_Username is extending TrustFrameworkExtensions from the local account starter pack. I can apply the same overrides from the "Local Account" ClaimsProvider over the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` and `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress` TechnicalProfiles to the "Local Account SignIn" ClaimsProvider's `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName` and `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress` TechnicalProfiles directly.

The policy inheritance looks like this:

```
LocalAccounts starter pack TrustFrameworkBase
                                        |
                                        v
LocalAccounts starter pack TrustFrameworkLocalization
                                        |
                                        v
LocalAccounts starter pack TrustFrameworkExtensions <- modified for custom emails via SendGrid
                                        |
                                        v
username-signup-or-signin sample TrustFrameworkExtenions_Username
                                        |                       |
                                        v                       v
username-signup-or-signin sample SignupOrSignin_Username and PasswordReset_Username
```

The display controls in local extensions from the how-to:

```
<DisplayControls>
  <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
    <DisplayClaims>
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
    </DisplayClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <Actions>
      <Action Id="SendCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
      <Action Id="VerifyCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
    </Actions>
  </DisplayControl>
</DisplayControls>
```

Tech profiles referenced from the display controls:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
      <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">1200</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
        <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
        <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
        <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">5</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
      <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
   </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>RestfulProvider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
      <DisplayName>Use SendGrid's email API to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SendGridSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

The SUSI tech profile overrides in the local extensions:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </DisplayClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
      <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
      </DisplayClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

I can get the sign-up part of the journey working in this manner - I could take the overrides in the extension changes found in the [how-to here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#make-a-reference-to-the-displaycontrol) and add the DisplayClaims to the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName` TechnicalProfile in
TrustFrameworkExtensions_Username.xml:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
    <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <DisplayClaims>
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    </DisplayClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

From the OutputClaim with `ClaimTypeReferenceId=email` `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"` was removed. Not necessary for getting the display control actually used but for later use of the email claim in the claim bag in a subsequent orchestration step (was not set otherwise).

But when updating the TechnicalProfile for `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress` in a similar way:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
  <DisplayName>Reset password using username</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordchange1.1</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
    <!-- Reduce the default self-asserted retry limit of 7 for the reset journey -->
    <Item Key="setting.retryLimit">3</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <!-- using this requires removal of OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true", below
  according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709880/2347078 -->
  <!-- line is required for non-customized email journey presently -->
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /> -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In this case, see the comments as to why the OutputClaim with `ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"` was modified, which is referencing [Jas Suri - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709880/2347078) below. With the OutputClaim looking like `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />` the display claim is ignored entirely (the built-in verification control is presented).

With the OutputClaim entirely removed, instead the password reset policy winds up not having any fields:

[image]

All starter packs/samples are from current repos, and are using v2 pages supporting display claims.

Answer (score 0):

Remove
`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />`

Comment: The description I had in there did not reflect what I had uploaded - it was just a case of the upload not taking effect yet with the run now link. Updated the post with what the actual effect of the policy was. The change suggested seems to not have any effect. Note that an OutputClaim like that appears in the other TechnicalProfile.

Comment: You should also make sure you’re using the latest page contract. Only v2 onwards supports display controls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-datauri-content-definition. And you definitely need to remove the line I mentioned already.